# How to access property in function by sending values from function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am sending values from function call

```
this.checkname("models", "name");
this.checkname("designers", "name");
```

i want to access my object.method by using a function call=>

```
checkname = (key, value) =>{
  const  models = this.state.model;
  const  designers = this.state.designers;
 if(key.value === ""){
   console.log("Unanamed");
  } 
}
```

i am not able to access (key.value) how to do that?

Comment: key is just a String  `"models"` or `"designers"` not an object

Comment: provide objects for model and designers for better understanding

Comment: i am using this.state.models and i am having model and designers as a object

Comment: const model ={ name:"testing", age: "12" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t use a variable to access an objects property with the „.“ notation instead use: `key[value]`.

This of course only works, if the value supplied as „key“ argument is an object (as was pointed out in the comments).

Edit: Ok now I seem to actually understand what you’re trying to do. If you want to use either `this.state.models` or `this.state.designers` depending on what string is supplied as `key`, you will have to supply some kind of condition (if-else) to decide which to use. Something along the lines of:

```
let person;
if (key === "models") {
    person = this.state.models;
} else if (key === "designers") {
    person = this.state.designers;
}
if (person[value] === "") {
    ...
}
```